# How can I stop Emacs (Cocoa OSX) making noise when scrolling and hitting the top of bottom of a buffer?

Tags: macos, emacs

How can I stop Emacs (Cocoa OSX, version 24.0.91 from http://emacsformacosx.com/builds) making noise when scrolling and hitting the top of bottom of a buffer when using the touchpad of my Macbook? I know I maybe should use the keyboard to scroll, but I'm so used to using the touchpad of my Macbook.

Comment: While setting `ring-bell-function` is an option, you might prefer to get visible feedback instead: (setq visible-bell t)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
(setq ring-bell-function #'ignore)
```

Comment: or:  `(setq ring-bell-function (lambda () (message "*beep*")))`